# How to print big array without a delay

Tags: c++

I am making this simulation in the terminal, and came up with a method to clear the terminal and then print out an array.

The problem occurs when an array is really big, like 40x40. There is a delay between printing out the first element and the last element. How do I print it without the delay?

This is the code:

```
void boardPrint(int rows, int columns, char** board)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        { 
            cout<<board[i][j]<<setw(2)<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

This is printing function:

```
boardPrint(rows + 2, columns + 2, board);
sleep_for(nanoseconds(10));
sleep_until(system_clock::now() + milliseconds(16)); 
system("cls");
```

This is how I implemented it combined with clearing the screen.

It looks pretty bad. I can see a cursor writing characters, and then the delay.

I could change the text colour, print it in black and then change the text's colour to white.

Comment: Remove the `cout<<endl;` and replace with `cout<<'\n';` each endl forces a flush. You may want to also run in Release mode.

Comment: Clear before printing, not after delay.

Comment: `system("cls");` is brutal and slow, it literally starts another program to clear the screen, so you might not get the speed you want no matter what you do. Unfortunately C++'s basic IO is really simple and not suited to this sort of behaviour. You may want to use a more complicated library like curses.

Comment: I remember the days when you could write directly to the screen buffer, and the output would be instantaneous.  Not sure if there is an analogous thing with today's video hardware.

Comment: @drescherjm "*each `endl` forces a flush*" - so does printing `'\n` when the output is line-buffered, which is usually the case.

Answer (score 4):

I would use an [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to build the output before printing to `std::cout` and I'd use whatever control codes your terminal uses to clear the screen directly (or use a library, like [pdcurses](/questions/tagged/pdcurses) to do it). I'm not even sure you should clear the screen. Just putting the cursor top left seems better and it'll flicker less too.

Example:

```cpp
void boardPrint(int rows, int columns, char** board) {
    std::ostringstream os;

    //os << "\033[H\033[2J";  // "home" + "cls" assuming you have an ansi terminal
    
    os << "\033[H"; // just "home" (upper left corner)

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            os << board[i][j] << '  ';
        }
        os << '\n';
    }

    // the output string is built, now print it
    auto str = os.str();
    std::cout.write(str.c_str(), static_cast<std::streamsize>(str.size()));
}
```

The actual loop could be rewritten to get a more stable updating by sleeping until a certain timepoint that you constantly add to. Like this:

```cpp
    auto tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while (game_is_on) {
        boardPrint(rows + 2, columns + 2, board);

        // ... other game logic ...

        tp += std::chrono::milliseconds(10);
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp);
    }
```

I would also consider using a `std::vector<std::string>` for the board and take that by `const&` in the printing function.

Comment: Is there a method to uese `std::cout.write()`?  The `write()` method would be faster since the data is already formatted.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Good idea. I changed to that instead.